# HBase and hadoop working together

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I'm looking for some resource on setting these up to work together that is with a more recent version.  All of the tutorials I see are for older versions of hadoop, does anyone know a good resource for 1.x?

Comment: You probably wanted to tell HBase and MapReduc working together? Since HBase is always run on top of Hadoop infrastructure

Comment: hbase doesn't need to use hdfs and by default it doesnt.

Comment: I think you miss something. HBase by default (in cluster) do use HDFS. W/O distributed file system HBase could not recover after region server failure, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Cloudera CDH3 or CDH4 guides to help you. Though you may have to reinstall your version of hadoop. I recommend Cloudera because they keep a repository that makes getting updates a breeze.

https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/HBase+Installation

I have run through this install a dozen times in the last week so if you run into any issues in particular hit me up.